# Equilibrium of a system of differential equations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with 4 real parameters.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let the following system of differential equations,
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    \dot{y} = b_1z + b_2[\gamma - (y^2 + z^2)]y \equiv f_{1,\gamma}(y,z) \\
    \dot{z} = c_1y + c_2[\gamma - (y^2 + z^2)]z \equiv f_{2,\gamma}(y,z)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

There is equilibrium when $\vec{f}_{\gamma}(y,z) = 0$ so,
\begin{align*}
  \vec{f}_{\gamma}(y,z) = 0
    &\iff
  \begin{cases}
    0 &= b_1z + b_2[\gamma - (y^2 + z^2)]y \\
    0 &= c_1y + c_2[\gamma - (y^2 + z^2)]z
  \end{cases} \\
    &\implies
  \begin{cases}
    b_1z &= b_2[\gamma - (y^2 + z^2)]y \\
    0 &= c_1y + c_2[\gamma - (y^2 + z^2)]^2 \frac{b_2}{b_1} y
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

We find then,
\begin{equation*}
  0 = y \left( c_1 - c_2 \frac{b_2}{b_1} \underbrace{[\gamma - (y^2 + z^2)]^2}_{\equiv \eta} \right)
\end{equation*}

Which implies that $y = 0$ if $c_1 \neq c_2 \frac{b_2}{b_1} \eta$ with $\eta > 0$

If $y = 0$ then $z = 0$ and $(y,z) = (0,0)$ is the only equilibrium of this system.

I'm wondering if what I found is true and if I could go further to find all the conditions on $c_1$, $c_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is $\frac{dy(t; \gamma)}{dt}$ and $\frac{dz(t; \gamma)}{dt}$

Comment: In that case, yes